# How to overcome "Could not load type 'Microsoft.Cct.Services.Sqm.IWatSqmService'" without updating?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net

I'm getting the same error message as in this question: [Could not load type 'Microsoft.Cct.Services.Sqm.IWatSqmService'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40861057/50151) Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade to Azure SDK 2.9, as the top answer there suggests.

Specifically, I get this error in a message box whenever I try to package my Azure Cloud Service project:

[image: Error message saying Could not load type 'Microsoft.Cct.Services.Sqm.IWatSqmService' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Services, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.]

What's interesting is that I can start the same project in the emulator, which I would assume involves packaging it.

Things I've tried:

1. Ensuring that I only have version 2.8.2 of the emulator installed (I may have had 2.9 installed initially)
2. Reinstalling version 2.8.2 of the SDK
3. Manually copying the `Windows Azure Tools` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0` to the `v14.0` equivalent.
4. Ensuring that `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.8` exists
5. Reinstalling Visual Studio (so you know I'm desperate!)

And I've no idea what to try next. I can't work out which DLL is supposed to hold the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Services` assembly, I can't find any references in any config files, and all the Google hits seem to point back to the SO question linked above.

**What's going on? And how can I fix it?**

---

In case I'm being an idiot, here's all the Azure-related things I've got installed:

[image: Screenshot of installed Azure programs]

Also (just in case it's relevant) I'm on Windows 7 SP1.

---

**Update 17/01/16**

Following some advice from the excellent [Rest Azured Slack channel](http://azured.io/), I've tried using ProcMon and Fusion Log to diagnose this (*spoiler: without success*)

ProcMon filtered to that assembly returns nothing:

[image: Screenshot of ProcMon showing no results]

Fusion log (set to log everything) yields lots of entries like this:

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (17/01/2017 @ 11:52:02) ***
>
> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
>   completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Services, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0/Common7/IDE/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = devenv.exe Calling assembly
>   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure, Version=2.9.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>   === WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with
>   Assembly.Load(). WRN: No matching native image found. LOG: IL assembly
>   loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Services.dll.

When I explore the DLL mentioned, I can find `Microsoft.Cct.Services.Sqm`, but it doesn't contain a type `IWatSqlService`:

[image: Screenshot of assembly explorer showing lack of IWatSqlService]

This feels like it's the crux of the issue, but I've no idea what to do next. Presumably I'd need to replace the DLL with a version that does define `IWatSqlService`, but I'm not sure where I'd get one. Or, for that matter, why it would even be necessary.

Next stop is probably a full wipe of the machine.

Comment: Are you mean that you have followed the similar issue above to uninstall all azure-related things and update/change your azure project to the equivalent version?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT I have tried everything *except* upgrading to 2.9, as this isn't an option for me. I have tried everything else in the post though.

Comment: I get this error with 2.9 as well, the related question suggests this as a fix but it's not really working

Comment: Hi @CyberDude. Sorry you're struggling too. That other question was the only other one I could find too. If you find a solution, I'd be really keen to hear it. In the meantime it looks like the next thing for me to try is to nuke my machine from orbit. :(

Comment: So far I could only notice that the web role seems to function correctly despite that publishing error... However don't take this as a guarantee, I'm not really testing the entire thing myself, I only help with its deployment to Azure, other people will then validate that all endpoints do what they're supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this problem. I ended up resolving this by nuking it from orbit. Fresh install of Windows, reinstall VS and the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, and solved it by **not using** the *Web Platform Installer*.

Download all parts (Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.8.2) from the Microsoft site: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50041 and follow the instructions how to install them.

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, you can also see this error when you add a new

```
<setting name="TODO" />
```

element to your `*.csdef` file but either:

1. forget to add the corresponding `<setting name="TODO" value="TODO" />` element to every `*.cscfg file`, or
2. accidentally add a duplicate `<setting name="TODO" value="TODO" />` element to any of the `*.cscfg` files.