# Cannot package Microsoft Cloud Service project, causes "Could not load type 'Microsoft.Cct.Services.Sqm.IWatSqmService' error

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk

I am running Visual Studio 2013 and a cloud service project using Microsoft Azure SDK version 2.5 that can't be upgraded to 2.9. It can't be upgraded because it uses Azure In-Role Caching which no longer works in Azure 2.9.

It appears that it can't find the assembly "Microsoft.VisualSudio.WindowsAzure.Services".

Steps to produce the error:

1. Open my solution in Visual Studio.
2. Right-click the cloud service
   project.
3. Select "Package"
4. Select "Package" again. note: all settings on this screen yield the same result.
5. get this error:

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Remove/reinstall the [Azure 2.5 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44938)
- Reinstall Visual Studio 2013
- After Reinstalling Visual Studio, reinstall Azure 2.5 SDK
- Uninstalled all other versions of Azure SDK and Tools
- Had all other members of my team package the project successfully on their machines.
- Install Azure SDK 2.6 and Tools
- [Upgrade to Azure SDK 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861057/could-not-load-type-microsoft-cct-services-sqm-iwatsqmservice)

I can't tell which package or component of the Azure SDK 2.5 install instructions I may have missed.

Next steps:

- Install Azure SDK 2.7
- Install Azure SDK 2.8

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but maybe this solution will work for you: [How to overcome "Could not load type 'Microsoft.Cct.Services.Sqm.IWatSqmService'" without updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630933/how-to-overcome-could-not-load-type-microsoft-cct-services-sqm-iwatsqmservice)
This one is look like the pretty same.